# Can these problems be blamed on a faulty dimmer switch in a 2003 Skoda Fabia 1.4 MPI (AQW)?

Tags: skoda

Here is the description of my problem occurring on my Skoda Fabia 1.4 MPI car, built in 2003:

- The green dashboard cluster illumination (that illuminates the speedo, rev counter, time and miles) is fully illuminated when I turn the lights on while not in ignition.
- The green dashboard cluster illumination becomes very dim (but stays on) when I turn on the ignition, or start the car.
- Dashboard warning lights (ie: battery indicator) work perfectly.
- Almost none of the cockpit guidance lights work (ie: charger, temperature control dials, electric windows). The notable exception is that the guidance light on the light switch dial (next to the dimmer) does work.
- The light dimmer has no effect whatsoever on anything.
- My external lights seem to work fine always, as do the curtesy internal lights (ie: the bright white light above the centre console, and the bright white light in the boot).
- However, the festoon-based number plate lights at the back of my car do not work, at all.

Based on the above, does anyone have any idea whatsoever as to how I could solve this problem? I wonder if it is the reason why I've recently had to purchase a new battery despite the fact that I had already bought and installed one myself half a year ago.

Here's a bonus oddity: If I turn the lights on without ignition, and someone closes or opens a door, then the green dashboard cluster illumination temporarily dims and then, after half a second, returns to being fully illuminated.

Any advice is much appreciated!

Nick

Comment: Which fuse? I have a similar situation and all fuses look fine. Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the fix required the replacement of a fuse.